# Access data stored within an .net Core cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have set up an an app with cookie authentication using open id Connect, like so:

```
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I now want to get the cookie from a request and interrogate it to get values from it.

I'm currently doing this:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"]
```

However the value of the cookie is currently encrypted for protection.

Q: What method / object can i use to decrypt my cookie to get my token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a specific token, you can use [`GetTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationtokenextensions.gettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's an example of getting both *access_token* and *id_token*:

```
var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
var idToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

This approach uses the default authentication scheme, which I'm *assuming* is set in your code accordingly. If it isn't, there's an overload of `GetTokenAsync` that also takes the `scheme`.